# How do I integrate a Polymer + Node.JS JavaScript app with React + TypeScript

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm, polymer

I have recently been tasked with integrating React + TypeScript with an existing starter app that contains many great Polymer Components (Predix UI Starter). I understand that this may seem non-sensical to some (after all, you could simply provide app state and logic using Polymer as a *framework*). However, the React *library* and the object oriented nature of TypeScript have a lot to offer, so what are some tips for getting started here?

Comment: Polymer + react doesn't work well, but it's been 2 years since I used it so it might have changed for the better.

Comment: Yeah I totally agree with you - personally I'd rather work with either/or. But the team I work on wanted me to do this so figured I'd post a quick POC here :)

Answer (score 0):

I will be integrating the [Predix UI Starter](https://github.com/predixdev/predix-webapp-starter) with the [create-react-app starter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter). Specifically, I will enable a React Component to render() a px-dropdown polymer component. This concept and method can apply to any polymer starter app. This **DOES NOT** completely integrate these two starters, it is **ONLY** a POC for rendering a polymer component in a React render() method, using TypeScript.

Clone both of these repos. Work out of the Predix UI Starter - this will contain all of the components once you run `npm install` and `bower install`.

Ensure that the `package.json` in the Predix UI Starter contains all of the *dependencies* and *devDependencies* that the react app contains. In the `package.json` file, in the `scripts` object, change `"start" : ...,` to `"start" : "react-scripts-ts start"`. This will serve the app to localhost using TypeScript (this is where the `tsconfig.json` and the `tslint.json` files come into play).

Copy the `tsconfig.json`, `tslint.json`, and the `tsconfig.test.json` files into the root directory of the Predix UI Starter.

As per the naming convention for React apps, rename the `server` folder to `src`. In the `.bowerrc` file, append `public/` before `bower_components`, this will enable the `public/index.html` file to import polymer components generated by bower. Unless configured to do so, `public/index.html` will be unable to load polymer components in parent folders to the `public` folder. (The user may need to configure the Predix Starter to initially serve the `public/index.html` file).

From the react starter to the Predix starter, copy the `App.tsx` and the `index.tsx` files to the `src` folder, and copy the `index.html` file to the `public` folder (this file will be what the app initially serves).

Add the `px-dropdown` component to the JSX namespace so that you can render it within a react component by adding a `global.d.ts` file to the root directory with the following content:

`declare namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
       'px-dropdown': any
    }
}`

You are now ready to render() the `px-dropdown` component. In the `public/index.html` file, import the component using the following two lines (within the `<head>` tag):

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html" />
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/px-dropdown/px-dropdown.html" />
```

Let's pass some `items` to the `props` of the `App` Component. In the `index.tsx` file, edit the line that renders the component to look like `<App items={'[{"key":"1", "val": "One"},{"key" : "2", "val": "Two"}]'}/>`

The following code in `App.tsx` will render the `px-dropdown` component successfully:

```
    class App extends React.Component<any, any> {
        constructor (props: any) {
          super(props);
        }
        render() {
          ...
          return (
            <div className="App">
              ...
              <px-dropdown
                items={this.props.items}
                sort-mode="key"
                button-style="default"
                display-value="Select"
                disable-clear>
              </px-dropdown>
            </div>
      );
    }
 }
```

You are now ready to begin rendering Polymer components using React + TypeScript.