# Getting props in Polymer which sent from React

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, polymer

How did I get the props in PolymerApp which you sent from ReactApp, I mean these:

```
<px-dropdown
  items={this.props.items}
  sort-mode="key"
  button-style="default"
  display-value="Select"
  disable-clear>
</px-dropdown>
```

Link to temp: [How do I integrate a Polymer + Node.JS JavaScript app with React + TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47333856/how-do-i-integrate-a-polymer-node-js-javascript-app-with-react-typescript/51759518?noredirect=1#comment90478844_51759518)
Thanks in advance!